EXCEPTION ERROR : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
When run the command rdd.count(), I am getting the error as below



rdd = sc.textFile("samplefile.txt")
rdd.count()



24/07/29 12:46:38 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 12)05]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:594)

Please help me out in getting the issue solved.
I tried by creating RDD with partitions as well but failed with same error.
